# Why is it neccessary to call up multiple people to read the Torah in synogogue?

Tags: torah-reading, torah-service

Wouldn't it make sense for one reader to do the whole thing?

Comment: I think calling multiple people helps involves the community and allows them to participate in the serves, as opposed to a rabbi (though he is learned).

Comment: Less prep work for any one person.